# Visual Studio doesn't let me make new projects or open old projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Heres a gif what I tried to do.

[image: https://gyazo.com/eb511dd7ac1064283a4bccb2c1f7323f]

^^ Tried to make a new project, didnt work.

Tried to open a project.

[image: https://gyazo.com/c06ca423c971d5daf8e21383e04654dd]

And also it gave me a template error.

Comment: Just a guess: You upgraded to SP2 of VS2015, didn't you.

Comment: Well, I just downloaded the community version of it. Thats all I did. EDIT: I have SP2

Comment: attach Windbg to the devenv.exe and when you see an exception in Windbg run **!analyze -v** to get details

Comment: Sorry I dont speak specialist.

Comment: run windbg (part of Debugging Tools for Windows from Win SDK), setup debug symbols (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588(v=vs.85).aspx#using_the_microsoft_symbol_server), in Windbg select attach to process, pick the devenv.exe. Now try to create a project and look if Windbg stops with an exception. if this is the cause run **!analyze -v** and post the output here